# FFMPEG in php return segmentation fault

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i am trying to convert file from php using ffmpeg! I have an Apache Linux server!

```
echo(exec("./ffmpeg -i ./input.wav ./output.mp3 2>&1"));
```

my output -> Segmentation fault

Someone can help me? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting segmentation faults output from FFmpeg, your FFmpeg binary is defective.  Get a new one, or compile it yourself from source.

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting in the dark:

- `exec ./ffmpeg` assumes executing from the current directory, is your directory current and proper?
- Could you run the same command manually, does it work? Could you do it under the same user your Apache runs under? (if it works under yours but not under Apache you might have permissions or dynamic linking libraries lookup problem)